# Safety of converting reference to int to reference to enum value

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

Given some `enum` or `enum class`, is it valid to convert either a reference or pointer to the underlying type of the `enum`, to a reference or pointer of the enum itself?

More concretely, is the following valid according to the C++ Standard:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

enum class Example : int { A, B };

int main()
{
    auto p = Example::A;

    // 'q' is the underlying type of 'Example'
    auto q = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Example>>(p);

    // Is this valid? Can 'r0' or 'r1' reference 'q' but projected as an 'Example'?
    auto& r0 = reinterpret_cast<Example&>(q);
    auto& r1 = *reinterpret_cast<Example*>(&q);
}
```

I don't really see any wording around references or pointers of integral values converted to references or pointers to `enum` types, so I'm uncertain here. The fact that `static_cast` rejects this code, requiring `reinterpret_cast` makes me suspect this is undefined behavior, or implementation-defined at best.

---

**A little background:**

My organization has noticed a lot of code-bloat due to containers with template types using strongly-typed enums. Normalizing these containers to integral instantiations has helped quite a bit, but doesn't preserve the type on the API -- so I would like to write some wrappers that do this for us.

Proxy reference-like-types could be used as well, but would break expressions like `auto& x = y[z]`. It would be convenient if it were possible to simply convert back-and-forth, since a delegation would be much simpler.

Comment: Dang, didn't think this was a duplicate! I'm glad someone else already asked this.